# TStringlist as function result, minimal code sequence

Tags: delphi

How to return a Stringlist from a function has been discussed many time before.
My code sequence version 1 is just a recap how to do it.

```
function GetStrings : TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.Add('string A');
  Result.Add('string B');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var stemp : tStringList;
begin
  stemp := GetStrings;
  MyListBox.items.addstrings(stemp);
  stemp.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyListBox.items.addstrings(GetStrings);
end;
```

is there any option to fix the memory leak in version2 with "no extra code", how dangerous is this approach at all, will this cause any failures if my stringlist is just a few string items, out of memory issues will not happen?

Comment: Any memory leak, no matter how small can eventually result with out of memory exceptions. The cause will not be lack of available memory, but the memory fragmentation. Meaning, if at some point you need to allocate some larger block of memory, you will not be able to do so, because there will be no continuous memory block large enough to accommodate such allocation. You should not tolerate any memory leaks, regardless of the leak size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to return a newly instantiated object from a function, there is a pattern for that. It goes like this:

```
function GetStrings: TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Result.Add('string A');
    Result.Add('string B');
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

This function behaves just like a constructor. Either it returns a newly instantiated object, and passes ownership to the caller. Or it raises an exception, and tidies up before raising it.

If you use this pattern, then you need to do so in the same way as you would with an object instantiated by a constructor, using the well known pattern:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  temp: TStringList;
begin
  temp := GetStrings;
  try
    MyListBox.Items.AddStrings(temp);
  finally
    temp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now, as for your direct question:

> is there any option to fix the memory leak in version2 with "no extra code", how dangerous is this approach at all, will this cause any failures if my stringlist is just a few string items, out of memory issues will not happen?

If you do return a newly instantiated object, then the caller can't avoid the responsibilities of ownership for that object.

Answer (score 14):

Don't use a `TStringList` as result type, but a `TArray<string>`. Of course this makes *version1* obsolete.

```
function GetStrings : TArray<string>;
begin
  var lst := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lst.Add('string A');
    lst.Add('string B');
    Result := lst.ToStringArray;
  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this is my favourite approach.

Comment: Why is that better?

Comment: @MatthiasB Because `TArray` is managed by the compiler, it is freed automatically when it goes out of scope. In this example, I wouldn't bother with the `TStringList`, though. I would just fill the array directly, eg: `function GetStrings : TArray<string>; begin SetLength(Result, 2); Result[0] := 'string A'; Result[1] := 'string B'; end;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think it should be pretty obvious that this is cut down code to demonstrate the problem. Also, your code is really verbose. You could use `Result := ['foo', 'bar'];` or `Result := TArray<string>.Create('foo', 'bar')`.

Answer (score 4):

As others as mentioned, you need to add extra code to both the function and the caller in order to manage the `TStringList` *correctly* to ensure it is always freed.

A better option is to not return a `TStringList` at all, but rather to take in any `TStrings` object the caller wants and just fill it in, eg:

```
procedure GetStrings(Strings: TStrings);
begin
  Strings.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Strings.Add('string A');
    Strings.Add('string B');
  finally
    Strings.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetStrings(MyListBox.Items);
end;
```

Comment: GetStrings is the wrong name for a function that appends to an existing collection.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is a matter of opinion and personal preference. There is nothing wrong with it in general, and functionally the compiler doesn't care.